# RAID5 on SmartArray P410i online resize

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, raid5, hp-smart-array

I have P410i+256M Cache without battery backup.
My RAID5 was build over 3*136GB disks, now all disks were replaced to a 3*300GB array.

How can I extend it to use the whole space?

HPacucli doesn't allows that, I think this might be because no battery is present.

I have a redundant power supply. All data is mirrored over DRBD to a secondary server, so I can try to resize with a chance of loss of data in case of power failure, but I prefer to have an online resize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have an online option. Online array/logical drive expansion with Smart Array controllers is only available with a battery or flash-backed cache unit. The online features leverage the cache unit heavily during online operations.

See the [Smart Array P410 Quickspecs](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13201_na/13201_na.html).

```
Management Features 
Online array expansion (with BBWC/FBWC upgrade)
Online Advanced Capacity Expansion (with BBWC/FBWC and Smart Array Advanced Pack upgrade)
Online logical drive extension (with BBWC/FBWC upgrade)
Online RAID level migration (with BBWC/FBWC upgrade)
Online strip size migration (with BBWC/FBWC upgrade)
```

In general, it's a good idea to have a BBWC/FBWC unit for HP RAID controllers. It'll certainly [improve the write performance on your RAID5 array](https://serverfault.com/questions/221541/incredible-low-disk-performance-on-hp-dl385-g7/221553#221553). [See this advisory](https://serverfault.com/a/282331/13325). Look for HP parts #534916-B21 or #462969-B21.

---

In order to initiate the expansion of your existing array offline, you can download the [HP SmartStart CD image](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-fa4e107ffbbd4ef394e57dd739%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) (or use the one that came with the server) and boot into the Array Configuration Utility (ACU) to make the appropriate changes to your array. Follow the array expansion instructions [listed in the ACU manual](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf).

Comment: OK, how i can extend it at all, without battery? I have no option right now to get battery :(

Comment: also, since i have additional DRBD replication, i'm just enabled write cache without battery.

Comment: See my comment above. I'd still recommend trying to find a battery, used or otherwise.

Comment: i have checked guide one more time, and still see no way to do that expansion in offline :( it still require battery..