# HP DL180 P410i Adding Additional Drive

Tags: centos, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a DL180 G6 HP P410i with 2x SATA in RAID1 running Linux CentOS.

Can I add (using the hot swappable drives) two more hard drives into the server and mount them without rebooting the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You'll want to use [`hpacucli` tool](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=5077022&prodNameId=5077027&swEnvOID=1110&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-37499d407ba04b078396a44a7d) to configure the new array. Rescan for new logical drives if your OS doesn't automatically, file system, mount, etc.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about hpacucli.

Is the download below suitable for CentOS 5/6?

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-66b08e49c28f4bd49f4641ed80

Comment: Yep, the latest RHEL packages should work find on CentOS as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

It depends upon what you intend to do upon inserting the disks.

You can plug them in, but they will need to be configured as a logical drive in order to be usable to the operating system.

If you want to expand the existing logical drive, the dynamic changes, and you may need to have a [battery-backed cache unit enabled on your controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/374349/raid5-on-smartarray-p410i-online-resize/374357#374357).

If running CentOS, you'll want to install the HP Management Agents or at the very least, the [**hpacucli** utility](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-37499d407ba04b078396a44a7d&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&).

---

The `hpacucli` utility has inline help, but to add a new pair of disks, something like:

```
ctrl all show config
```

Shows the running configuration.

Based on the output, you'll want to create a new **logical drive** of **RAID 1** using the unassigned disks... Something like:

```
ctrl slot=1 create type=ld drives=2I:1:3,2I:1:4 raid=1
```

Where *slot* is the controller's PCIe slot number from the first command, and the *drives* are the disk port numbers from the first command.

Once you make this change and exit the utility, a new block device will be available at the OS level. `dmesg | tail` will show this. From there, you can `fdisk` the new device and create filesystems/partitions on top of it.

Comment: I want to add two more hard disks in a RAID 1 format. 

In the end there will be 2x RAID1 configurations

Comment: @John In that case, it can be done hot without any disruption to the running OS.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Using hpacucli How do I make pay 3 & 4 active and set in RAID1 configuration?

Also, will the cause any issues on reboot?

Comment: @john You won't have to reboot for this. See my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have a P410i? The DL180 GP does not have a P410i option.

Either way, yes, the controllers that come as standard equipment on a DL180 G6 do support hot-add. If you have the HP ACU CLI installed, you can create the logical drive from within your OS. Then rescan using your OS tools and mount.

Comment: A few of the configurations come with a P410, ok it's not the 'i' version but functionally it's the same. (see http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13248_na/13248_na.HTML for confirmation).